# Optimize Django ORM query to get object if a specific related object does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following table structures:

```py
class Library:
    id = models.CharField(...)
    bookcase = models.ForeignKey(
        Bookcase,
        related_name="libraries"
    )
    location = models.ChoiceField(...)
    # Other attributes...

class Bookcase:
    # some attributes
    type = models.ChoiceField(..)

class Book:
    bookcase = models.ForeignKey(
        Bookcase,
        related_name="books"
    )
    title=models.CharField(...)
    status=models.ChoiceField(...) # borrowed | missing | available
```

Say if I want to get all Library objects that does not have a book with title "Foo" that is NOT missing, how can I optimize this query? I have the following:

```py
libraries = Library.objects.select_related('bookcase').filter(location='NY', bookcase__type='wooden')

libraries_without_book = []
for library in libraries:
    has_non_missing_book = Book.objects.filter(
        bookcase=library.bookcase,
        title="Foo",
    ).exclude(status='missing').exists()
    
    if not has_non_missing_book:
        libraries_without_book.append(library.id)
```

Unfortunately, this performs an extra query for every Library object that matches the initial filtering condition. Is there a more optimized method I can use here that makes use of `prefetch_related` in some way?

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.objects.filter(~Q(status='missing'),bookcase=library.bookcase,title='Foo')
```

This query should be sufficient

Comment: I don’t want the Book object though, I want the Library object here

Comment: libraries = Library.objects.select_related('bookcase').filter(location='NY', bookcase__type='wooden').select_related("book").filter(~Q(status='missing'),title="Foo")

How about this ?

Comment: You can't use `select_related` on the Library model for Book since it only has a foreign key to Bookcase. But I figured out how to optimize it using prefetch_related. Will be updating this post soon